# Given two natural numbers $m, n$ so that $m> n.$ Prove that there exist any real numbers $x$ so that $2\sin nx\cos mx\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, continuity, substitution

> Given two natural numbers $m, n$ so that $m> n.$ Prove that there exist any real numbers $x$ so that (unsolved in a case..)
> $$2\sin nx\cos mx\geq 1$$
> Source: StackMath/@RiverLi_ [Prove: $(\forall m, n\in\Bbb N_{>0})(\exists x\in\Bbb R)$ s. t. $2\sin n x \cos m x \ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3715384/822157) .

I couldn't find a concrete value of $x,$ but I succeeded at proving the problem by using Intermediate value theorem (My friend has taught me a solving plan..). Let $x$ on the interval $I= \left [ -\frac{5}{6}\pi, \frac{\pi}{6} \right ],$ we call $f\left ( x \right ):=\frac{1}{2\sin x}, g\left ( x \right ):=\cos\alpha x, \alpha:=\frac{m}{n}> 1,$ I devide my problem into 2 cases as followings

*When* $1< \alpha< \frac{6}{5},$ we have $f, g$ continuous both and $f\left ( -\frac{3}{4}\pi \right )\geq g\left ( -\frac{3}{4}\pi \right ),$ by Intermediate value theorem $\exists x\in I$ so that $f\left ( x \right )= g\left ( x \right )$

*When* $\alpha\geq\frac{6}{5},$ we have $f, g$ continuous and $\exists x\in I$ so $g\left ( x \right )= -1\Rightarrow\exists x\in I$ so that $f\left ( x \right )= g\left ( x \right )$

**Conclusion**.
$$\forall\alpha= \frac{m}{n}> 1, \exists x\in I: f\left ( x \right )= g\left ( x \right )\Leftrightarrow\forall m, n, \exists x\in I: 2\sin x\cos\alpha x= 1$$
$$\Rightarrow\forall m, n, \exists x\in \mathbb{R}: 2\sin nx\cos mx\geq 1$$
I'm waiting for @RiverLi's complete solution and want to see such a value of $x$ for my proof, thanks

Comment: Thanks. "there exist any real numbers $x$" should be "there exists a real number $x$"?

Comment: In my question, we can say "there exists a $x = r \pi$ where $r$ is a rational number such that $2\sin nx \cos m x \ge 1$".

Comment: Do you mean there exist more than one such $x$?

Comment: I edited my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715384/prove-forall-m-n-in-bbb-n-0-exists-x-in-bbb-r-s-t-2-sin-n-x-cos

Comment: Your approach is nice. (+1) But such a $x$ may not be the form of $x = r\pi$ for some rational?

Comment: I'm not sure of

Comment: Thus, I made a bounty for you, hope one guy can beat it !

Comment: I visited this link_ https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1845103p12418278, hope you post the question and your attempt on StackMath

Comment: Thanks. That question is something like a calculus assignment/homework. Also I have a solution. So it is not suitable for MSE.

Comment: But I want to ask it, I'll post it soon..

Comment: I only can solve DE by Wolfram|Alpha, how to solve it by a good method, maybe you have it ??

Comment: I think you can search some handouts about DE.

Comment: Can you introduce some of articles to me ??

Comment: You can search MSE. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907809/book-recommendation-for-ordinary-differential-equation

Comment: Thank U@RiverLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach comes from looking at the graphs of the involved functions.

Given $m>n>0$ put  $$m+n=:p\geq3,\qquad m-n=:q\geq1\ .\tag{1}$$ We have to study the function
$$f(t):=2   \sin(nt)\cos(mt)=\sin(pt)-\sin (qt)$$
on the  circle ${\mathbb T}:={\mathbb R}/(2\pi{\mathbb Z})$. After scaling the $t$-axis appropriately we may assume ${\rm gcd}(p,q)=1$. The function $t\mapsto\sin(pt)$ has $p$ equidistant local maxima (value $=1$) on  ${\mathbb T}$, color them red, and the  function $t\mapsto-\sin(qt)$ has $q$ equidistant local maxima (value $=1$) on  ${\mathbb T}$, color them blue. Denote by $\delta\geq0$ the minimal distance between a red and a blue maximal point. I claim that $$\delta\leq{\pi\over p q}\ .\tag{2}$$
*Proof.* When a red and a blue point coincide we have $\delta=0$. In this case it follows from [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) that there are two more red/blue pairs,  with opposite order along ${\mathbb T}$, having distance ${2\pi\over pq}$. When the blue pattern of points is then rigidly rotated vs.\ the red pattern the two coinciding points are disassociating, while one pair of distance ${2\pi\over pq}$ points is going to combine. The worst case is in the middle, when the rotation angle is ${\pi\over pq}$. At that moment  the $\delta$ of the situation is just covered by $(2).\quad{\square}$

We therefore have a red maximum at $\xi\in{\mathbb T}$ and a blue maximum at $\eta\in{\mathbb T}$ with $$\delta:=|\xi-\eta|\leq{\pi\over pq}\ .$$ Let $\tau$ be the point between $\xi$ and $\eta$ having distance ${q^2\over p^2+q^2}\delta$ from $\xi$ and  ${p^2\over p^2+q^2}\delta$ from $\eta$. We are now going to estimate $f(\tau)$.

In the neighborhood of $t=\xi$ the graph of $t\mapsto\sin(pt)$ is congruent to the graph of
$$t\mapsto\cos(pt)\geq1-{p^2\over2}t^2$$
in the neighborhood of $t=0$. It follows that
$$\sin(p\tau)\geq 1-{p^2\over2}(\tau-\xi)^2\geq1-{p^2\over2}\left({q^2\over p^2+q^2}\delta\right)^2\ .$$
Similarly we have
$$-\sin(q\tau)\geq 1-{q^2\over2}(\tau-\eta)^2\geq1-{q^2\over2}\left({p^2\over p^2+q^2}\delta\right)^2\ .$$
Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we now obtain
$$f(\tau)\geq2-{p^2q^2\delta^2\over 2(p^2+q^2)}\geq2-{\pi^2\over 2(p^2+q^2)}>1\ .$$

*Example:* When $m=3$ and $n=2$ then $p=5$, $q=1$. Our estimate then gives $f(\tau)\geq1.81$. This value is indeed realized by $f$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a rl lot

Answer (score 1):

Extended comment ($a=\alpha$).

Your proof is hard to follow.
First, you have not specified a point $x\in I$, s.t. $f(x)<g(x)$. Second one cannot apply IVT on the interval $I=\left[-\frac{5\pi}6, \frac{\pi}{6}\right]$ because the function $f(x)$ is not continuous on this interval. Third the claim that there exists a point with $g(x)=-1$ in the chosen interval is not proven.

Below I will try to remedy these shortcomings. First we define the interval to be $I=\left[-\frac{3\pi}4, -\frac{\pi}{3a}\right]$. Clearly both functions are continuous on this interval and
$f\left(-\frac{\pi}{3a}\right)<g\left(-\frac{\pi}{3a}\right)=\frac12.$ So we need only to show that there is a point $x\in I$, s.t. $f(x)>g(x)$.

Similarly as in you proof we let the point be $x=-\frac{3\pi}4$ for $1<a<\frac43$. For larger $a$ we can choose any point $x$ such that $\cos(a x)=-1$, $-\frac{3\pi}4\le x<-\frac{\pi}4$ (this choice is somewhat artificial and done only due to some symmetry).
To find $x$ we need to resolve the following inequality for $k\in\mathbb Z$:
$$
-\frac{3\pi}4\le -\frac\pi a(2k+1)<-\frac{\pi}4\iff \frac a4<2k+1\le\frac{3a}4.\tag1
$$
The essence here is: for $a>\frac43$ the inequality $(1)$ always has at least one solution. Observe that $k=0$ is the only solution of $(1)$ for $a<4$ and cancels to be a solution for $a>4$. This however does not harm  as we can take $k=1$ for $4<a<\frac{20}3$. For higher values of $a$ multiple solutions for $k$ are possible (though smaller $k$ repeatedly cancel to be the solutions).